# Woocommerce archive-product.php overwrite not working with underscores.me theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, underscores-wp

i have done this things and i have double checked all things

in plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php

i have just copy to my-themes/woocommerce/archive-product.php to override the core woocommerce file.

but it's not working only with  underscores.me before i tried many time but it's working but in latest updates it's not working

WC version:     3.3.5 
Server info:        Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
PHP version:        5.6.33-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

```
my_theme/woocommerce/archive-product.php, 

my_theme/woocommerce/content-product.php, 

my_theme/woocommerce/content-product_cat.php, 

my_theme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php, 

my_theme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php, 

my_theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php, 

my_theme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php, 

my_theme/woocommerce/single-product/short-description.php, 

my_theme/woocommerce/single-product.php, 

my_theme/woocommerce/taxonomy-product_cat.php
```

Comment: I could reproduce the same error here. Instead of using the file from the `woocommerce` folder inside the theme, the file called `content-page.php` is being used. This file is present in the `template-parts` folder of the underscores theme.

Comment: just i found the solution here @HareeshSivasubramanian
we have to just pass 
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );  

please read this page also 
https://pmgarman.me/add-woocommerce-support-to-underscores/

and no need to add woocommerce.php in theme folder

Comment: Thanks for the update, Suraj!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i just fount the solution after some research we need to just add below function into our themes functions.php file

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

please read this page also you will get exactly idea about theme support and other things
https://pmgarman.me/add-woocommerce-support-to-underscores/
it's working for me with underscores.me themes

Comment: Why this is not added by default when installing the plugin!!

Comment: It's theme related issue not plugin

Comment: It keeps happening to me.. Thanks for helping me out on an hour head scratch !